# Annotations with lines on D3 bar charts

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, charts

I would like to add annotations to an SVG bar chart written in D3.

I want to add lines and text to the chart, like the below:

[image]

My question is: is there a best practice for this or general pattern?

My assumption would be to use a .each method following the data `.enter() method`. Using a conditional operator, should then be possible to call a function that inserts rendered line paths and text.

Comment: Presumably these annotations come from some data? I would add this completely separately to the rest; that is, draw the bars first, then do a separate pass where you select annotation `g`s and pass in the data for the annotations.

Comment: I'd agree. If it were me, I'd put the annotations in some other structure, and assign each one a unique class.  Then somehow flag the bars (in the original data) with the appropriate matching class. Then call them at the same time when you draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple out-of-the-box options that can help:

[Swoopy Arrows](https://github.com/bizweekgraphics/swoopyarrows)

[Swoopy Drag](https://github.com/1wheel/swoopy-drag)

[D3-ring-note](https://github.com/armollica/d3-ring-note)

[Poly-label](http://bl.ocks.org/Fil/da021023d58b8ddefd165c65e37f796b)